# SwiftUI - offset wrong or weird padding?

Tags: swiftui

I'm creating a schedule app and im trying to render the activities on a calendar sort of thing. Im doing this by having a set spacing of 20 between every hour mark. This means that to position the activities I can take the hour the activity start times this set height of 20 to position it correctly. This does indeed work but when I add multiple activities the offset is wrong? But if I render every activity on its own the offset is correct.

This is the code for displaying the activities.

```
    struct Event: Hashable {
    var name: String
    var start: Int
    var end: Int
    var y: CGFloat
    var eHeight: CGFloat
    var color: Color
}



struct EventIndicatorView: View {
    var day = [Event]()
    
    init() {
        day.append(createEvent(name: "Matematik", start: 8, end: 9, color: Color.blue))
        day.append(createEvent(name: "Svenska", start: 10, end: 11, color: Color.green))
        day.append(createEvent(name: "Fysik", start: 12, end: 14, color: Color.red))
        day.append(createEvent(name: "Idrott", start: 15, end: 16, color: Color.pink))
    }
    
    func createEvent(name: String, start: Int, end: Int, color: Color) -> Event {
        let eHeight = CGFloat((end - start) * height * 2)
        //let y = CGFloat((start*height*2) + height)
        
        let y = CGFloat((start*2*height)+height*(end-start))
        
        let e = Event(name: name, start: start, end: end, y: y, eHeight: eHeight, color: color)
        
        return e
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(day, id: \.self) { d in
                HStack() {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        HStack(spacing: 0) {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(d.color)
                                .frame(width:5, height: d.eHeight)
                            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(d.color.opacity(0.5))
                                    .frame(height: d.eHeight)
                                    
                                Text(d.name)
                                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 4, leading: 4, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                                    .foregroundColor(d.color)
                                    .font(.subheadline.bold())
                            }
                        }
                        .cornerRadius(4)
                        .offset(x: 60, y: d.y)
                            
                    }
                    
                }
                .frame(height: CGFloat(height))
            }
               
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
}
```

This is the code for showing the hours.

```
var hours = [String]()

struct CalenderView: View {
    init() {
        for hour in 0...24 {
            if hour == 24 {
                hours.append("00:00")
                return
            }
            
            if hour <= 9 {
                hours.append("0\(hour):00")
            } else {
                hours.append("\(hour):00")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack(spacing: CGFloat(height)) {
                ForEach(hours.indices, id:\.self) {index in
                    HStack(spacing: 10) {
                        Text(hours[index])
                            .frame(width: 40, height: CGFloat(height))
                            .font(.caption.bold())
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color(.systemGray4))
                            .frame(height: 1)
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                    
                }
                
            }
       
    }
}
```

This code results in this:
[Display of multiple acctiviys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Vl8.png)

The green one should be positioned on 10 but isn't.

Here is a picture where I only display one activity:
[Only one activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4XAK.png)

But if I only display the green one its position is correct

Comment: What is the height variable in your code? It is not defined in your snippet

Comment: Height is an integer of 30